# Create expression is not immutable

Tags: postgresql

using the below I get **ERROR: generation expression is not immutable** why? I've read the docs and most talk about concat being an issue but I'm not using that anywhere so where's my issue?

```
CREATE TABLE public.source
(
    width integer NOT NULL,
    sha1 uuid NOT NULL,
    height integer NOT NULL,
    lastupdated date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (current_timestamp) STORED,
    PRIMARY KEY (sha1)
);

ALTER TABLE public.source
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an immutable expression (i.e. one that always produces the same answer given the same inputs) as `current_timestamp` produces different answers on subsequent calls.

Comment: Hmmm so I guess I can’t get it to auto fill in the created column with the current date/time?

Comment: No, you would need to either set it as a default value, or, given you've named the column `lastupdated`, you would probably want a trigger instead that would update that column's value whenever a row is updated.

Comment: so I should keep the column as nullable? and use a trigger?